# Каст обьектов в рантайме

Tags: c#, cast

Дано 1:

```
public abstract class BaseEntityViewModel<T> where T : RealmObject
{
    public T SomeMethod()`;
    //какие-то проперти
}

public class SomeClass1 :RealmObject {}

public class SomeClass2 :RealmObject {}
```

Дано 2:

```
IList<T> origObjList; //List<RealmObject> -- получаю его в рантайме

IEnumerator<T> currObjList; // List<BaseEntityViewModel<SomeClass>> -- получаю его в рантайме
```

Итак здесь сразу 2 вопроса:

1. Как мне сказать что-то вроде:

   ```
    ((where have SomeMethod)currObjList).SomeMethod();
   ```

   То есть как мне сказать предкомпилятору что я могу вызывать метод `SomeMethod()` при этом не указывая напрямую тип? (я его наперед просто не знаю, а указывать родительский класс или интерфейс не могу) Даже если я получу object как работу метода -- не важно.
2. Я знаю что я могу получить из дано2 значение типа `Т` в рантайме; 
   Как мне кастовать в рантайме результат прошлого пункта в даный Т? Если учесть, что конвертирование скорее всего не сработает... Как мне сделать запись "(TypeSomeType)objectRez" когда `TypeSomeType` хранится в someTypeVariable

Comment: не уверен достаточно ли понятно написал, если нужно исправлять -- пишите

Comment: Желание задать (и получить ответ на) такие вопросы - показатель того, что что-то не так в датском королевстве.

Comment: в моем случае - просто попытка написать один хитрый универсальный метод. Который уже на 95% написан.

Comment: Желание написать "хитрый универсальный" код ведет прямиком в ад.

Comment: Я сам с этим утверждением согласен. В основном, но не в этом случае. Этот "костыль" очень сильно уменьшит мне количество кода и повысит его читабельность. Прям ОЧЕНЬ сильно.

Comment: здесь можно применить `dynamic`

Comment: не, в конкретно даном случае dynamic не выйдет, я думал над этим вариантом до того как создавал вопрос. Но спасибо)

Comment: @Andrew, почему? все то же самое - и проверка наличия свойства в run-time

Comment: мне нужно сделать копию всех элементов из `currObjList` в `origObjList`, который является `IList<T>` где `T` является `RealmObject`. В некоторых случаях нужно вызвать у обьекта метод `GetOrigObject()` что бы получить обьект `T`. В некоторых -- не нужно. Если я создам динамический обьект я не cмогу добавить его в `origObjList`как мне нужно, т.к. он не будет имплементировать `RealmObject`, а это обязательно.

Comment: ну или я как-то не так понял идею реализации через `dynamic`

Comment: @Andrew, ну так dynamic на то и dynamic, что проверка осуществляется в run-time. Если в нем будет лежать объект типа Т - добавление пройдет успешно.

Comment: С каждым новым вашим вопросом запашок от `Realm` все сильнее и сильнее. Может это только в его версии под дотнет всё так печально, не знаю...

Comment: @АндрейNOP cкорее всего это я его так использую) Попробуй, уверяю, тебе понравится с ним работать) Мне после SQLite с ним работать одно удовольствие. Но так же ты прав что .Net версия хуже чем для других языков... Увы.

Comment: Ну есть тот же `LiteDB`, который работает с обычными `POCO` и не требует наследования от куска фреймворка, все проблемы у вас скорее всего из-за этого ограничения

Comment: @АндрейNOP Кстате, на реалм меня подсадил программер со стажем в 15 лет работавший на многих серьезных проэктах, в основном по геймдеву. В том числе и ААА класса. :) Может, это уберет "запашок" от хорошей либы появившийся от моих глупых вопросов  :)

Comment: судя по гуглению, LiteDB не имеет поддержки реактивности из коробки и имеет какие-то проблемы с iOS... Лично для меня это минусы, хотя, скорее всего, многим будет пофиг.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
T result = (T)(obj.GetType().GetMethod("SomeMethod")?.Invoke(obj, null));
```

Comment: а по поводу каста в рантайме (вопрос 2) ?

Comment: там не известен Т наперед, как и сказано в вопросе... Но я его могу достать в переменную что бы потом каким-то хитрым макаром кастовать. Представь что у тебя есть переменная `Type origType` в которой есть этот `Т`

Comment: Динамически - есть ф-ция `Convert.ChangeType`, но "template" в ряде случаев более удобен.

Comment: не уверен сработает ли здесь, я сейчас ее опробую и если что отмечу ответ как верный

Comment: @Andrew У меня ощущение, что Вы понимаете что-то свое под словом "cast". `Invoke` возвращает ссылку на `object`. В действительности по этой ссылке находится объект определенного типа, независимо от того, применяете Вы к нему cast или нет.

Comment: @nick_n_a, `ChangeType` возвращает object

Comment: @Grundy мне достаточно того, что оно возвращает object. Я уже метод дописал, вроде все пашет, хотя я не проверил все возможные кейсы. Возможно еще что боком вылезет, но пока что все пашет так как я и хотел) Моментально убрал кучу кода который нужно было поддерживать вручную =^_^= Теперь меньшая возможность что я где-то по невнимательности налажаю

Comment: Даже моментально пофиксилось несколько багов в уже существующем функционале. Я доволен =^_^=